# Strategy not opening any trades

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm having a problem with a strategy, specifically that it doesn't open any trades at all. I tried to debug this as much as I could and my debug labels are showing exactly where a trade should be opened. However, no trade at all is ever opened.

The strategy is used on US500 index on Capital.com with settings of 1H timeframe and 3 SFP on HTF confirmation candles and 2 SFP on LFT confirmation candles. No time-limited backtesting is used - but even if I use it and set it to the last month only, nothing changes.

Here's the strategy I'm trying:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title = "Candle Squeeze Strategy", shorttitle="Squeeze Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true, calc_on_order_fills = true, pyramiding = 0, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 75, commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = 0.04, initial_capital = 100, max_bars_back = 5000, max_boxes_count = 500, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)

GROUP_PA_OPTIONS             = "Price Action Options"
GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS = "Time-Limit BackTests (0 = disable)"

i_tf = input.timeframe( "60", "TF to look for Squeeze in", group = GROUP_PA_OPTIONS )
i_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation = input.int(3, "Confirm Squeeze on HTF by this many candles", minval = 0, tooltip = "We will check this many candles in the same direction as was the trend before HTF Squeeze to see if there was a continuous rise / fall in that trend right before the Squeeze. For example, in a downtrend followed by a Squeeze, we will check X red continuous candles right before Squeeze was found. If we cannot find this many continuous candles in that downtrend, we will not open any trades for that Squeeze.", group = GROUP_PA_OPTIONS)
i_ltf_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation = input.int(2, "Confirm Squeeze on LFT by this many candles", minval = 0, tooltip = "We will check this many candles in the same direction as was the trend before LFT Squeeze to see if there was a continuous rise / fall in that trend right before the Squeeze. For example, in a downtrend followed by a Squeeze, we will check X red continuous candles right before Squeeze was found. If we cannot find this many continuous candles in that downtrend, we will not open any trades for that Squeeze.", group = GROUP_PA_OPTIONS)
TPPerc = input.float( 2, title="Take Profit (%)", minval=0.1, step=0.1, group = GROUP_PA_OPTIONS)
SLPerc = input.float( 1, title="Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.1, step=0.1, group = GROUP_PA_OPTIONS)

i_use_time_limited_backtesting = input.bool( false, "Use Time-Limited Backtesting", group = GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS )
i_startDay = input.int(0, "Start Day", minval = 0, maxval = 31, group = GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS)
i_startMonth = input.int(0, "Start Month", minval = 0, maxval = 12, group = GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS)
i_startYear = input.int(0, "Start Year", minval = 0, maxval = 2100, group = GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS)

i_endDay = input.int(0, "End Day", minval = 0, maxval = 31, group = GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS)
i_endMonth = input.int(0, "End Month", minval = 0, maxval = 12, group = GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS)
i_endYear = input.int(0, "End Year", minval = 0, maxval = 2100, group = GROUP_TIME_LIMITED_BACKTESTS)

inDateRange = true

var tf_last_bar_index = -1
var last_candle_type = ""
var last_candle_close = -1.0
var prev_candle_type = ""
var prev_candle_close = -1.0
var first_candle_type = ""
var first_candle_close = -1.0
var squeeze_plotted = false
var htf_squeeze_found = false
var recorded_squeeze_type          = ""  // squeeze type
var recorded_squeeze_price_level   = 0.0 // squeeze price to get back to, break below/above and then return through it
var recorded_squeeze_bar_index     = 0   // squeeze bar index, so we don't check agains the same bar we found the squeeze on
var price_crossed_recorded_squeeze = false // once true, we'll wait for the price to cross the recorded squeeze again and then we'll start checking for the next printed FVG
var price_squeeze_cross_bar_index  = 0   // bar index where our price crossed the recorded squeeze

var last_trade_ts = time
var min_trade_gap_minutes = 2

var order_types = array.new_string( 1, "" ) // order type
var our_active_orders_count = array.new_int( 1, 0 )
var order_prices = array.new_float( 2 ) // 0 = exit price, 1 = stop price

if array.size( order_prices ) == 0
    array.fill( order_prices, 0.0, 0, 1 )

// Look if the close time of the current bar falls inside the date range
if i_use_time_limited_backtesting and i_startDay != 0 and i_startMonth != 0 and i_startYear != 0 and i_endDay != 0 and i_endMonth != 0 and i_endYear != 0
    inDateRange := ( time >= timestamp( syminfo.timezone, i_startYear, i_startMonth, i_startDay, 0, 0 ) ) and ( time < timestamp( syminfo.timezone, i_endYear, i_endMonth, i_endDay, 0, 0 ) )

//Convert a given string resolution into seconds
ResolutionToSec(res)=>
    mins = res == "1" ? 1 :
           res == "3" ? 3 :
           res == "5" ? 5 :
           res == "10" ? 10 :
           res == "15" ? 15 :
           res == "30" ? 30 :
           res == "45" ? 45 :
           res == "60" ? 60 :
           res == "120" ? 120 :
           res == "180" ? 180 :
           res == "240" ? 240 :
           res == "1D" ? 1440 :
           res == "1W" ? 10080 :
           res == "1M" ? 43200 : 0
    ms = mins * 60

// }

if ResolutionToSec( i_tf ) < ResolutionToSec( timeframe.period )
    runtime.error("Strategy timeframe must be higher or equal than current timeframe.")

// searches for the Xth value in the prices_array, since we may have multiple same values in that array for the same HTF candle
// and we need for example the 1st, 2nd and 3rd value from that HTF
findHistoryCandle( prices_array, bar_index_array, current_bar_index, candle_num_to_return ) =>
    last_b_index = current_bar_index
    candles_counter = 0
    ret = 0.0

    for i = 0 to array.size( bar_index_array ) - 1
        if array.get( bar_index_array, i ) < current_bar_index and array.get( bar_index_array, i ) != last_b_index
            last_b_index := array.get( bar_index_array, i )
            candles_counter := candles_counter + 1
            if candles_counter == candle_num_to_return
                ret := array.get( prices_array, i )
                break

    [ ret, last_b_index ]

// squeeze detection
string squeeze_type = na
history_array_length = 75
[ candle_open, candle_close, tf_bar_index ] = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, i_tf, [ open, close, bar_index ], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off )

tf_bar_index_array = array.new_int()
for i = 0 to history_array_length
    array.push( tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[ i ] )

candle_open_array = array.new_float()
for i = 0 to history_array_length
    array.push( candle_open_array, candle_open[ i ] )

candle_close_array = array.new_float()
for i = 0 to history_array_length
    array.push( candle_close_array, candle_close[ i ] )

// bar index has changed, update candle values
if tf_last_bar_index == -1 or tf_last_bar_index != tf_bar_index
    last_candle_type := candle_close > candle_open ? "up" : candle_close < candle_open ? "down" : ""
    last_candle_close := candle_close
    [ prev_close_price, prev_bar_id ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_close_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], 1 )
    [ prev_open_price, prev_bar_id2 ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_open_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], 1 )
    prev_candle_type := prev_close_price > prev_open_price ? "up" : prev_close_price < prev_open_price ? "down" : ""
    prev_candle_close := prev_close_price
    //prev_candle_index := prev_bar_id
    [ first_close_price, first_bar_id ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_close_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], 2 )
    [ first_open_price, first_bar_id2 ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_open_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], 2 )
    first_candle_type := first_close_price > first_open_price ? "up" : first_close_price < first_open_price ? "down" : ""
    first_candle_close := first_close_price

    squeeze_plotted := false

    // only update last bar index here from the higher TF if we're initializing
    if tf_last_bar_index == -1
        tf_last_bar_index := tf_bar_index

// squeeze in swing low
if prev_candle_type == "up" and last_candle_type == "down" and first_candle_type == "down" and last_candle_close < prev_candle_close and first_candle_close < prev_candle_close
    squeeze_type := "down"
    
    // check previous X candles for trend confirmation?
    if i_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation > 0
        for i = 2 to 2 + i_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation
str.tostring( findHistoryCandle( candle_open_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i ) ) + " / " + str.tostring( findHistoryCandle( candle_close_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i ) > findHistoryCandle( candle_open_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i ) ) )
            [ candle_close_price, candle_bar_id ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_close_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i )
            [ candle_open_price, candle_bar_id2 ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_open_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i )
            if candle_close_price > candle_open_price
                squeeze_type := na
                //squeeze_candle_index := 0
                break

// squeeze in swing high
if prev_candle_type == "down" and last_candle_type == "up" and first_candle_type == "up" and last_candle_close > prev_candle_close and first_candle_close > prev_candle_close
    squeeze_type := "up"

    // check previous X candles for trend confirmation?
    if i_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation > 0
        for i = 2 to 2 + i_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation
tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i ) ) + " / " + str.tostring( findHistoryCandle( candle_close, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i ) < findHistoryCandle( candle_open, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i ) ) )
            [ candle_close_price, candle_bar_id ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_close_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i )
            [ candle_open_price, candle_bar_id2 ] = findHistoryCandle( candle_open_array, tf_bar_index_array, tf_bar_index[0], i )
            if candle_close_price < candle_open_price
                squeeze_type := na
                break

plots_offset = math.floor( ResolutionToSec( i_tf ) / ResolutionToSec( timeframe.period ) )

plotshape(not squeeze_plotted and not na(squeeze_type) and squeeze_type == "down", color=color.green, title="Squeeze Down", text="Squeeze", style=shape.labelup, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, offset = -plots_offset, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(not squeeze_plotted and not na(squeeze_type) and squeeze_type == "up", color=color.red, title="Squeeze Up", text="Squeeze", style=shape.labeldown, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, offset = -plots_offset)

// we only want the first squeeze candle marked
if not na(squeeze_type)
    squeeze_plotted := true

// squeeze detection on current TF when HTF squeeze was found
string squeeze_type_ltf = na
last_candle_type_ltf = close > open ? "up" : close < open ? "down" : ""
last_candle_close_ltf = close
prev_candle_type_ltf = close[1] > open[1] ? "up" : close[1] < open[1] ? "down" : ""
prev_candle_close_ltf = close[1]
first_candle_type_ltf = close[2] > open[2] ? "up" : close[2] < open[2] ? "down" : ""
first_candle_close_ltf = close[2]

if squeeze_plotted or htf_squeeze_found
    htf_squeeze_found := true
    // squeeze in swing low
    if prev_candle_type_ltf == "up" and last_candle_type_ltf == "down" and first_candle_type_ltf == "down" and last_candle_close_ltf < prev_candle_close_ltf and first_candle_close_ltf < prev_candle_close_ltf
        squeeze_type_ltf := "down"
    
        // check previous X candles for trend confirmation?
        if i_ltf_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation > 0
            for i = 2 to 2 + i_ltf_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation
                if close[i] > open[i]
                    squeeze_type_ltf := na
    
    // squeeze in swing high
    if prev_candle_type_ltf == "down" and last_candle_type_ltf == "up" and first_candle_type_ltf == "up" and last_candle_close_ltf > prev_candle_close_ltf and first_candle_close_ltf > prev_candle_close_ltf
        squeeze_type_ltf := "up"
    
        // check previous X candles for trend confirmation?
        if i_ltf_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation > 0
            for i = 2 to 2 + i_ltf_squeeze_num_prev_candles_confirmation
                if close[i] < open[i]
                    squeeze_type_ltf := na

    // reset this variable, as we'll show our LFT squeeze now
    if not na(squeeze_type_ltf)
        htf_squeeze_found := false

plotshape(i_tf != timeframe.period and not na(squeeze_type_ltf) and squeeze_type_ltf == "down", color=color.blue, title="LTF Squeeze", text="LTF Squeeze Down", style=shape.labelup, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, offset = -1, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(i_tf != timeframe.period and not na(squeeze_type_ltf) and squeeze_type_ltf == "up", color=color.maroon, title="LTF Squeeze", text="LTF Squeeze Up", style=shape.labeldown, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, offset = -1)

// reset if we plotted LTF squeeze and store the squeeze candle properties
if not na(squeeze_type_ltf)
    recorded_squeeze_type := squeeze_type_ltf
    recorded_squeeze_price_level := squeeze_type_ltf == "down" ? high[1] : low[1]
    recorded_squeeze_bar_index := tf_bar_index[0]
    squeeze_type_ltf := na
    // reset these 2 if we crossed a recorded squeeze but failed to act on it
    if price_crossed_recorded_squeeze
        price_crossed_recorded_squeeze := false
        price_squeeze_cross_bar_index  := 0

// broker section
trade_type = array.get(order_types, 0)
exit_price = array.get(order_prices, 0)
stop_price = array.get(order_prices, 1)

// close trades when price reaches our target
exit_bool = array.get( our_active_orders_count, 0 ) > 0 and (trade_type == "Buy" ? close >= exit_price : close <= exit_price )
if exit_price > 0 and strategy.opentrades > 0 and exit_bool
    strategy.close( trade_type, comment = trade_type + " TP reached" )
    array.set(order_prices, 0, 0.0)
    array.set(order_prices, 1, 0.0)
    array.set(order_types, 0, "")
    array.set( our_active_orders_count, 0, 0 )
    recorded_squeeze_type          := ""
    recorded_squeeze_price_level   := 0.0
    recorded_squeeze_bar_index     := 0
    price_crossed_recorded_squeeze := false
    price_squeeze_cross_bar_index  := 0

// remove trades from internal cache when they reach SL
sl_bool = array.get( our_active_orders_count, 0 ) > 0 and (trade_type == "Buy" ? close <= stop_price : close >= stop_price )
if stop_price > 0 and strategy.opentrades > 0 and sl_bool
    array.set(order_prices, 0, 0.0)
    array.set(order_prices, 1, 0.0)
    array.set(order_types, 0, "")
    array.set( our_active_orders_count, 0, 0 )
    recorded_squeeze_type          := ""
    recorded_squeeze_price_level   := 0.0
    recorded_squeeze_bar_index     := 0
    price_crossed_recorded_squeeze := false
    price_squeeze_cross_bar_index  := 0

// check whether the current price crossed our squeeze price yet
if recorded_squeeze_type != "" and price_crossed_recorded_squeeze == false and tf_bar_index[0] != recorded_squeeze_bar_index and ( ( recorded_squeeze_type == "up" and close < recorded_squeeze_price_level ) or ( recorded_squeeze_type == "down" and close > recorded_squeeze_price_level ) )
    price_crossed_recorded_squeeze := true
    price_squeeze_cross_bar_index := tf_bar_index[0]

label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring( price_squeeze_cross_bar_index ) )

var debug = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, border_width = 1)

// check whether we're not crossing the recorded squeeze price back again
table.cell(table_id = debug, column = 0, row = 0 , text = "trades: " + str.tostring( strategy.opentrades ) + " / rec_sq_t: " + recorded_squeeze_type + " / crossed: " + str.tostring( price_crossed_recorded_squeeze ) + " / idx: " + str.tostring( price_squeeze_cross_bar_index ) + " != " + str.tostring( tf_bar_index[0] ) + " / lvl:  " + str.tostring( recorded_squeeze_price_level ), bgcolor=color.black, text_color=color.white)
if strategy.opentrades == 0 and recorded_squeeze_type != "" and price_crossed_recorded_squeeze == true and tf_bar_index[0] != price_squeeze_cross_bar_index and ( ( recorded_squeeze_type == "up" and close >= recorded_squeeze_price_level ) or ( recorded_squeeze_type == "down" and close <= recorded_squeeze_price_level ) ) and inDateRange and ( ( time - last_trade_ts ) / 1000 >= ( 60 * min_trade_gap_minutes ) )
    // open a trade here
    type = recorded_squeeze_type == "down" ? "Buy" : "Sell"
    strategy.entry( type, type == "Buy" ? strategy.long : strategy.short )

    // calculate TP
    TP = 0.0
    if ( type == "Buy" )
        TP := close + ( ( TPPerc / 100 ) * close )
    else
        TP := close - ( ( TPPerc / 100 ) * close )

    label.new(bar_index, low - 20, "trade - " + type + " at " + str.tostring( close ) + ", tp " + str.tostring( TP ) )

    // calculate SL
    SL = 0.0
    if ( type == "Buy" )
        SL := close - ( ( SLPerc / 100 ) * close )
    else
        SL := close + ( ( SLPerc / 100 ) * close )

    label.new(bar_index, low - 40, "exit - " + str.tostring( SL ) )
    strategy.exit( type, stop = SL, comment = "closed by SL" )

    array.set( order_types, 0, type )
    array.set( our_active_orders_count, 0, 1 )
    array.set( order_prices, 0, TP )
    array.set( order_prices, 1, SL )
    last_trade_ts := time

// update last bar index
tf_last_bar_index := tf_bar_index

// Exit open market position when date range ends
if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, so that I could test, I ignored the 2 error lines:137,152 by simply deleting them.
Then ignored/ corrected line 222 by `nz(low[1])` to get to the real problem that lies in the strategy definition: `default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity`. If you leave it to the default fixed, or increase your initial_capital, your strategy will be executed.

Comment: thank you, that did never occur to me that the investment percentage could be the culprit - also, sorry for those 2 lines, they were brought into the code by mistake as I was removing unneccessary comments

Comment: No problem! By such monster scripts it can easily happen. Since your debugging was working correctly and there were no more syntax/compile errors it must have been the strategy definition itself that prevented you from executing even a single strategy entry.

Comment: would you have an idea why that would happen though? with a 100USD capital, 75% equity per trade and 0.04 commission, I would say that at least some trades should happen - at least a single one - since there is enough capital at the very beginning... it puzzles me that TV would not open a single trade in such instance

Comment: I'm actually experiencing that with other strategies as well on FOREX... perhaps this is an issue for a question of its own - here's a sample of different strategy that just doesn't seem to work correctly at all (1mil capital, 1% per trade, 0% commission and the second (loosing) trade has a -$12.40 profit - which if I invest 1% of 1mil = 10000USD is just completely nuts of a result) - https://imgur.com/a/P4OEngt

Comment: I think you should open a question for that that someone more experienced can answer.